# Не добавляются CORS заголовки Sanic

Tags: python, cors, sanic

Не добавляются CORS заголовки в response headers

```
app_sanic = Sanic(name='git_check_alive')
app_sanic.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

cors = CORS(app_sanic, resources={
    r"*": {
        "origins": "*",
        "methods": ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE"],
        "allow_headers": ["content-type", "token"],
    }
})
```

В ответных заголовках вообще ничего не меняется, как будто CORS просто не видит. Не понимаю что делаю не так. `{'content-length': '825', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'content-type': 'None'}`

Comment: А эту переменную Cors вы куда потом устанавливаете? Попробуйте через расширения еще https://sanic.dev/en/guide/how-to/cors.html

Comment: @Mira, к сожалению не понимаю нужно ли ее куда то устанавливать, в [описании](https://pypi.org/project/Sanic-Cors/) я не нашел никакой информации, что делать с данной переменной

Comment: Там в описании несколько вариантов, этот вы пробовали? @app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin(app)
def hello_world(request):
  return text("Hello, cross-origin-world!")

Comment: @Mira, да, пробовал. У меня headers вообще не меняется, такое чувство что где то что то надо включить, но по мануалу непонятно.

Comment: Так погодите, хедерс не должны меняться, должен меняться доступ - то есть с браузера он должен начать работать

Comment: @Mira, из того что я накопал headers все-же должен меняться. Но и в браузере тоже проверил, CORS error ((((((

Comment: Попробуйте еще этот вариант, там и как залогировать и как вручную добавить https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62028771/sanic-cors-exception-handler